# Usinc Command Promt / Shell in Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, command-prompt

As title, what command/class can i used for that? and if the function is exist whether function to get callback from commandshell?

Comment: You can use Socket connection to commicate with cmd.exe. So if you want to communicate with CMD, you must make one c/c++/visual-c++ project which call all the operation of cmd/ shell of your requirement, afterword you can communicate with this project's executable file and when your project has result it return a o/p to the socket connection. see More about Socket in its Documentaion => http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html

Answer (score 2):

You can run and communicate with other processes in AIR as per [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html).

So, if you wanted to run the Windows command prompt, you would have to provide the location of cmd.exe which is "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe". Unfortunately, AIR won't understand %windir%, so you will have to actually provide the full path to the Windows directory (usually C: but you will have to figure out how to handle cases where it is not C:).

Annoyingly, the command prompt does not seem to act like a normal input stream; I receive errors when trying to write to it. There may be some way around that that I don't know about it. Instead though, you can just start the command prompt with your arguments.

For instance, the following code will start a command prompt (assuming Windows is on C), print "hello" and trace the output (which in this case will just be "hello").

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"); 
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file; 
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
processArgs.push("/C echo 'hello'");
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs; 
process = new NativeProcess(); 
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("Got: ", NativeProcess(event.target).standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable)); 
}
```